# What is the recommended way of creating Serverless (or) AWS lambda functions on the fly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm creating a SaaS product which allows users to create their own apps. For each application I need to deploy a serverless app or just a lambda function with cloud watch events & api gateway configurations through cloud formation stack when a particular request hits my backend API (which is also a serverless application). I need to know the best practice or the recommended way of achieving that task.

There are two approaches I found by doing a bit of research.

1. Using aws sdk and create a cloud formation stack. (without using the serverless framework)

2. Using serverless-platform-sdk which deploys an app on [serverless-platform](https://dashboard.serverless.com/) (beta) which I'm not completely sure about.

Comment: ... if you're trying to dynamically deploy new lambdas upon users' actions, then it already feels like a really fishy approach.
If you actually use the Serverless Framework (as one of your tags suggests) then the framework will actually generate a CloudFormation stack for you as soon as you type `serverless deploy`. And yes, you want to create CloudFormation stack. This way you can easily group all the resources that are linked to your lambda. So if you have a lambda with a log group, it's own API Gateway and DB and you don't want them any more, you can delete the stack along with all stuff

Comment: @KamilJanowski why do you think it as a fishy approach? I thought of using the aws-sdk to create cloud formation stack. Serverless doesn't provide an sdk to deploy apps from the code level. What I suggested as the second approach is using serverless-platform-sdk which is a new product by serverless (Still beta).

Comment: it feels a bit like dynamically creating more tables in the database instead of designing it in a right way. Moreover deploying a lambda takes quite a bit of time. Dropping it quite ironically can take even more and often fails due to relations to other resources that were created during the runtime.
Is it the same lambda deployed every time but with a different trigger? If so, then perhaps it would be easier and faster to manage only the triggers?

Comment: and if it's actually end-user's code that is deployed to the lambda... it would still feel better to have just one lambda that dynamically loads the code from S3, because that again can be executed in 2 seconds, rather than 5+ minutes required just to create the stack for your new lambda